# Why are my requests requiring authentication failing after the initial logging in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm  working on a MERN app and experiencing this bizarre issue in which any request (to the server) for a resource that requires the user to be authenticated after the initial logging in fails. Specifically, the first time I open the browser and go the landing page at `http://localhost:3000`, I'm prompted to log in. I duly proceed then get redirected to `/home`. It is here that I experience said issue as I get an `Unauthorized` error message rather than the expected list of posts. Obviously, this is from a failed a request to the server for said list when the `HomePage` component is mounted, which requires a user to be authenticated. This keeps on happening to any subsequent requests that require authentication and only after I refresh the browser (and thus auto-login, as seen below) does this issue get resolved.

I'm attaching the authentication token (if present) to all requests, as seen in the `axios` requests config below. So, what gives?

**Axios config**

```
import axios from 'axios';

function requestWithAuthTokenSetToHeaders() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const defaultOptions = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token && `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  return {
    get: (url, otherOptions = {}) =>
      axios.get(url, { ...defaultOptions, ...otherOptions }),
    post: (url, data, otherOptions = {}) =>
      axios.post(url, data, { ...defaultOptions, ...otherOptions }),
    put: (url, data, otherOptions = {}) =>
      axios.put(url, data, { ...defaultOptions, ...otherOptions }),
    patch: (url, data, otherOptions = {}) =>
      axios.patch(url, data, { ...defaultOptions, ...otherOptions }),
    delete: (url, otherOptions = {}) =>
      axios.delete(url, { ...defaultOptions, ...otherOptions }),
  };
}

export default requestWithAuthTokenSetToHeaders;
```

**App entry/index.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import configureStore from './store';
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from './store/auth/types';
import {
  FETCH_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_CURRENT_USER_FAILURE,
} from './store/users/types';

import App from './components/App';
import Spinner from './components/shared/spinner';

import { requestWithAuthTokenSetToHeaders } from './utils';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

const request = requestWithAuthTokenSetToHeaders();

// Get authenticated user's info
async function getUserInfo(token) {
  try {
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await request.get(`/users/me`);

    localStorage.setItem('current-user', JSON.stringify(user));

    if (user) {
      store.dispatch({
        type: FETCH_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: FETCH_CURRENT_USER_FAILURE,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
}

// Auto login to account
async function autoLogin() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (token) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    });

    getUserInfo(token);
  }
}

autoLogin();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<Spinner />} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I am sure your token is not getting to the backend hence the unauthorized.  I will suggest you search online on how to use interceptors with axios to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Do you see the auth header sent in the requests? (Network Tab)

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine That's exactly what's happening. For whatever reason, the token is not attached/sent to the backend that first time. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll promptly look it up.